# Bootstrap Modal Opacity only to specific div not for whole body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to apply edit bootstrap build in Modal properties... I want to apply for opacity to only specif div not for whole body(default) how to we fix this?

```
<div class="container">

  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
 <div class="change_me" id="changeme1">
 some div content
 </div>
```

When click on `Open Modal` pop up opens by changing the css property of body to `opacity:0.6` but i am trying to apply opacity only for class `.change_me` how can we achieve this?

Comment: you don't fix you alter

Comment: .change_me {opacity:0.6} in css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean you don't need all body show opacity,just for div.change_me,you can set this :

```
.modal-backdrop, .modal-backdrop.fade.in {
     opacity: 0!important;
     filter: alpha(opacity=0)!important;
 }
```

the set you div.change_me:

```
.change_me{
      opacity: 0.6!important;
      filter: alpha(opacity=60)!important;
 }
```

then let div.change_me at right place;(edit for wrong number;)

Comment: Similar to it.. but what i mean  is instead of whole body.. when we click on open modal, only `.change_me` should get opacity

Comment: i think it should be fine ;).